# Зачем нужен ThreadLocal если объект и так будет кешироваться если не стоит volatile?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Всем добрый вечер, вопрос про ThreadLocal и volatile.

Насколько я знаю, **volatile** используется для того, чтобы объект хранился в общей памяти, а не в кеше процессора. **ThreadLocal** используется для того, чтобы объект хранился исключительно в своем потоке.

Так вот вопрос: Зачем нужен **ThreadLocal** если объект и так будет кэшироваться если не стоит **volatile**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так никто не обязан кэшироваться.

То, что без `volatile` что-то может закэшироваться, вовсе не означает, что при любых условиях оно будет кэшироваться. К тому же, кэш не резиновый - даже то, что туда попало, не будет лежать там вечно.

А `ThreadLocal` говорит, что у каждого потока должна быть своя копия, не зависящая от других. Соответственно, ей можно безопасно пользоваться внутри потока и не ждать, что она вдруг почему-то неожиданно изменится (впрочем, привет таскам и пулу потоков).

Comment: Меня вот всегда интересовало а зачем вообще нужна переменная, которая доступна нескольким потокам, а ее значение нет? Смысл тогда с этой расшаренной переменной, если всегда можно приватной\локальной обойтись?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko ну, например, именно в такой переменной хранится объект который возвращает функция `Thread.currentThread()`

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, смысл обычных переменных в том, что на них нет дополнительной логики, влияющей на скорость работы программы. В обмен на это программист обещает не использовать их из разных потоков одновременно.